# can't sudo mv libtinfo.so.5.bak libtinfo.so.5

Tags: linux

One hour ago, I `mv /lib64/libtinfo.so.5 /lib64/libtinfo.so.5.bak`, then the others cannot `ssh` server. Their's error message looks like this:

> -bash: error while loading shared libraries: libtinfo.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>   Connection to 10.60.242.30 closed.

I want to change this file back, `sudo mv /lib64/libtinfo.so.5.bak /lib64/libtinfo.so.5`

> bash: error while loading shared libraries: libtinfo.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

it seems like a deadlock that `sudo` would use `libtinfo.so.5`.

I have tried `LD_PRELOAD=./libtinfo.so.5.bak sudo mv /lib64/libtinfo.so.5.bak /lib64/libtinfo.so.5`, it doesnot work.

Anybody can help me ?

Comment: Do you have access to the physical server or the server hosting the VM (if it's a VM)? Then the easiest way would be to turn it off, rename the file and turn it back on. Other then that: You could ssh as root into the machine without a shell and rename it (`ssh root@machine mv /foo.bak /foo`)

Comment: Seems like that it is the only way to solve it. Although physical server is tens of miles away from us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mv` fails because `sudo` sees the parameter list and decides that it requires a shell to interpret it.  Some other *simple* commands may work (in a quick check, for instance, I don't see an intermediate `sh` when doing `sudo visudo`).  If that's so, you could write and compile a simple program that you execute using `sudo`, e.g.,

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void)
{
    rename("/lib64/tinfo.5.bak", "/lib64/tinfo.5" );
    return 0;
}
```

Another possibility would be a script, e.g., in Perl which appears to not have a dependency upon ncurses:

```
$ ldd `path perl`
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffd0f9f6000)
        libperl.so.5.14 => /usr/lib/libperl.so.5.14 (0x00007fcfc33ba000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fcfc31b6000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fcfc2f34000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fcfc2d18000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fcfc298b000)
        libcrypt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007fcfc2754000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fcfc373c000)
```

If you have physical access to the server, a workaround like this is not *necessary* (since you could load a recovery DVD and fix the server offline).  If you do not, and have only ssh access (e.g., in Amazon AWS), you would have to use a workaround like this.

Further reading:

- [Getting Console Output and Rebooting Instances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-console.html) (Amazon)

Comment: Last night I `exit` terminal for some season, nobody could `ssh` that server because of the `bash` error, not mention to execute `sudo`. I think the only way to do this was ride to data center, connect LCD and keyboard to our server, login as `root`, `mv /lib64/libtinfo.so.5.bak /lib64/libtinfo.so.5`.